# LSTM model (in Keras) with different number of rows for each input

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, sequential

So I am trying to fit a simple LSTM model in Keras.

My data looks like this:

```
Student ID, feature1,feature2,feature3, feature..21 time,labely
1,  some value , some value, some value,time1,..,  y1
1,  some value , some value, some value,time2,..,  y2
1,  some value , some value, some value,time3,..,  y1
1,  some value , some value, some value,time4,..,  y1
2,  some value , some value, some value,time1,..,  y1
2,  some value , some value, some value,time2,..,  y2
3,  some value , some value, some value,time1,..,  y1
3,  some value , some value, some value,time2,..,  y2 
3,  some value , some value, some value,time3,..,  y1
```

So for each student I have different number of observations as you can see.I want to build a LSTM which learns the sequence of observations to predict the y label. The number of features is fixed=21.

I am a newbie to LSTMs and I am facing the following problems starting with data dimensions:

Problem 1: My input format is :

```
X[0]:
[array([[  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   8.34490000e+04],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   8.34490000e+04],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   8.34490000e+04],
       ...,
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   7.11650000e+04],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   7.11650000e+04],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   7.11650000e+04]], dtype=float32)]
```

My output format is:

```
y[0],y[1]:
 [array([  1.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   0.,  nan,   0.,
        nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   1.,  nan,  nan,   1.,   1.,  nan,
        nan,  nan,  nan,   1.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan], dtype=float32)
 array([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   0.,  nan], dtype=float32)]]
```

The np.shape output is giving me (19,) for y  and (33,) for x . I am not able to reshape it to 3D array.

Problem 2: my lstm is in

https://codeshare.io/5zv4ok

The error I am getting is:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (19, 1)

I want to know how to proceed with my model. I am also confused about how to set the time step parameter since it varies for each student.

Answer (score 0):

Keras needs one multidimensional array to turn it into a tensor (in tensorflow or whatever backend you're using). So generally it's not possible to call fit with varying dimesnions besides the batch_size.

1. There are several possible solutions for your problem: You could pad
   your sequence with zeros so that every sample has the same sequence
   len (the easiest solution)
2. You can sort your samples in batches, in which each batch has a
   specific sequence len and then feed it into your networks
3. Train your model with batch_size=1